# How to show plotly graphs when viewing jupyter notebook on GitHub

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I am using Jupyter on VS code, the graphs work fine when views on VS code, however when I upload the ipynb file on GitHub none of the graphs show up

Code:

```
import plotly.express as px
countryc = px.histogram(country_count , "Country" , color='type').update_xaxes(categoryorder = "total descending")
countryc.show()
```

I tried saving the the graph as an html file using :

```
countryc.write_html('/Python/Netflix EDA/countryc.html')
HTML(filename='/Python/Netflix EDA/countryc.html')
IFrame(src='/Python/Netflix EDA/countryc.html',  width = 1300, height=700)
```

however I am still unable display this file when viewing on GitHub. Any suggestion on how to show the interactive files on GitHub?

Comment: how does `country_count` get it's value ?

Comment: @ShanavasM you can have a look at the code [link](https://github.com/Axjet/DataCamp/blob/main/Netflix%20EDA/netflix_eda.ipynb)